# How to create maven project as dependent jar to other projects without dependencies

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, project

I have a java project called "A" it has some custom annotations implemented in spring aop way and it is packaged as jar using maven jar plug-in, which contains only classes specific to project of A without any dependencies.now i have installed it in local maven repository using install command (mvn install:instlal-file) and used it as dependency in another maven project called "B".

I can able to  get those annotations in project "B" but i cannot get dependencies automatically from pom file in dependent jar(project "A").due to which building project "B" is failing.

Q1: should we put all dependencies which we are using for project "A" in project "B" pom as well?
Q2: or it could get automatically downloaded from dependent jar pom file?
Note: am not interested in fat jar? but its working fine if we mention all dependencies in project "B". is there any way to get all dependencies when we build project "B" automatically?

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your error was to use `mvn install:install-file`. If you do not add the POM as parameter, an (almost) empty POM is created for you.

The right way:

- Go to project A and run `mvn clean install`.
- Then use A in B, and enjoy full transitive dependency resolution.

So, to summarize, the answer for Q1 is "no", and the answer for Q2 is "yes, use `mvn clean install` instead of `mvn install:install-file`.

Comment: Thanks for reply...but am using mvn install:install-file(mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path of jar> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true) is to install the generated jar into local reposiroty(.m2 directory). am using mvn clean install to build the project then only the jar file (contains only classes specifically using in project "A" without any dependencies). This generated jar(project "A") has pom inside meta-inf directory in jar file, so dependencies inside this pom will automatically download in project "B".?

Comment: my POM from project "A"

Comment: <build>
  <plugins>
  
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <archive>
      <manifest>
       <mainClass>main class</mainClass>
       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
      </manifest>
     </archive>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

Comment: No. As I said: If you use `install:install-file` with `generatePom=true` you loose all dependencies of that jar. POMs from inside the jar do not matter, they are ignored. For your own projects, always use `clean install`, never use `install:install-file`.

Comment: yes..i did it (mvn clean install ) for project "B" after placing project "A" dependency in project "B" pom.xml ..event am getting classnotfoundexception for which am trying to utilize the classes from jar.

Comment: because i see no dependent jars are downloaded from project "A" custom jar. how do i get downloaded automatically into project "B" classpath.

Comment: Yes, but you need to run `mvn clean install` on project A.

Comment: yes of course i do then only got 2 jars created in target folder one which suffix with "jar-with-dependencies" and second one is small jar which does not contain any dependent jars..basically am interested in second one to use it as dependent on other project like "B".

Comment: You confuse me: First you said, you used `mvn install:install-file`,  now you say you use `mvn clean install`. It is important that you understand that `mvn install:install-file` _destroys the POM_.